# Extend Interface and apply object of super Interface

Tags: typescript

Let us assume I have the following

```
export interface Project {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    metaModel: { name: string, id: number };
    createdAt: string;
    lastEdited: string;
    visibilityLevel: VisibilityLevel;
    members: string[];
    m0files: M0File[];
}
```

and I extend it like this

```
interface ProjectAndMembership extends Project{
    owner: boolean;
}
```

How could I apply an object/a variable of Project to the new interface ProjectMembership so that I only have to provide a boolean for the owner value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I apply an object/a variable of Project to the new interface ProjectMembership so that I only have to provide a boolean for the owner value?

You have at least two choices:

1. Create a new object, perhaps via `Object.assign`:

   ```
   let x:ProjectAndMembership = Object.assign({}, {owner: true}, theProject);
   ```

   [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYCsILMgbwChlTlgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG4SyB6AKgDp-unIgF8ioSLEQp02XGACCICgFkIzaAGcAFsAAOyCAA9ISjWkw48hDqQwB3ENBpMMGADYQ4IdqKIf8YFoQMpZgNCFyyAC8hJQ0ACwATMLsfhD4hlQReIoqaixQ2nrRyADyTKG8cBoawADmIAAUBMIANIT2jlA0YFB0EG3IgcEWcgCUrEA)
2. Use a type assertion and just add the property to the existing object:

   ```
   let x:ProjectAndMembership = theProject as ProjectAndMembership;
   x.owner = true;
   ```

   [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYCsILMgbwChlTlgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG4SyB6AKgDp-unIgF8ioSLEQp02XGACCICgFkIzaAGcAFsAAOyCAA9ISjWkw48hDqQwB3ENBpMMGADYQ4IdqKIf8YFoQMpZgNCFyyAC8hJQ0ACwATMLsfhD4hlQReIoqaixQ2nrRyIHBFpFwZtkKSqrqhTq67Ia89o5QJWBQdBCsQA)

I'd lean toward #1.